# Radical of an ideal using Macaulay2 software.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, math-software, macaulay2

> What is the radical ideal of $(u^2v-a^3,uv^2-b^3,uv-ab)$ in $\mathbb{C}[u,v,a,b]?$

Above all, to learn how to fish, what would be code that I can use to get the radical? I have not worked with Macaulay2 (computational algebra software) before, so what is a good reference to learn about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code gives the radical of your ideal:

```
R = QQ[u,v,a,b]
I = ideal (u^2*v-a^3,u*v^2-b^3,u*v-a*b)
radI = radical I
```

So, according to Macaulay2, we have $\sqrt{I} = (a^2-ub,va-b^2,uv-ab)$.

Beware, computing radicals can be extremely slow if you have many generators, because the algorithm must compute a Gröbner basis first. However, in this case, the ideal is binomial, and there are extremely efficient algorithms for computing with binomial ideals. (in Macaulay2, the package "BinomialIdeals" does this).

**Some (two) references on how to learn Macaulay2:**

- [The Macaulay2 homepage.](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/GettingStarted/) Here are four guides that will teach you the basics. Follow them step-by-step.
- The Macaulay2 book [*Computations in Algebraic Geometry with Macaulay2*](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/Book/). Lots of examples. And the whole book is available free in all sorts of formats.

Comment: Dear @Fredrik, thank you, it is very helpful.

Comment: By the way, could you add some references for learning how to use Macauley2?

Comment: @ehsanmo: Sure. I've added two helpful links. See the post.